# Make tabpanel header unclickable

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, tabpanel

I having an application which allow user to report cases. I have done it using a `Tab Container` which have 5 `Tab Panel` in it. The user required to report accordingly to the 5 panel I included. In the `Tab Panel` I have insert 2 button for the user to go to the next or previous tab. I don't wish to let the user jump to the next tab by clicking on the `Tab Panel Header` so I want to disable the header from clicking it but with the header there. After doing some research, I realise that it possible to do it using javascript. I don't really understand on how to use javascript  to disable the tabpanel header. So do help me out on how to disable tabpanel header other than using of javascript. Thanks!